# Equivalence of categories of coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $Z$ be a closed subscheme of noetherian scheme $X$ and $U = X-Z$. Let $M(X)$ denote the abelian category of coherent sheaves on $X$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ = $ \lbrace \mathcal{F} \in M(X) : \mathcal{F}_{\lvert U} = 0 \rbrace$ be the full subcategory of $M(X)$. I want to show that the quotient category $M(X)/\mathcal{B}$ is equivalent to $M(U)$.

I defined a functor $L : M(X) \rightarrow M(U)$ by $L(\mathcal{F}) = \mathcal{F}_{\lvert U}$. Clearly this functor has kernel category $\mathcal{B}$ so it induces a faithful functor $U : M(X)/\mathcal{B} \rightarrow M(U)$ and $U$ is also essential surjective since $L$ is. Because every coherent sheaves on $U$ is a restriction of some coherent sheave on $X$. But I am unable to prove that $U$ is full. I did if $X$ is affine scheme but don't know in general. Any help would be great.

Comment: You can prove it directly, but I would rather find an inverse $R$ of $L$ and prove that $R\circ L$ and $L\circ R$ are both isomorphic to the identity.

Comment: How will you define R?

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking of $R$ the composite $p\circ j_*$ where $p:M(X)\to M(X)/\mathcal{B}$ is the canonical functor and $j:U\to X$ is the inclusion. Unfortunately $j_*$ does not preserve coherence.